# What is the meaning of the academic title "Karsh."?

Tags: titles, iran

I have recently started my work at a new institute.
One of the employees there is from Iran.
Their academic title is "Karsh." and "Karsh.A.".

A short Google search revealed that "Karsh" is either a surname or a village in Iran.
I have never seen these titles and I am curious on what they describe.
Is this something similar to a Bachelor/Master’s degree?

Comment: Maybe a [Karsh scholar](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeMwZ7KO4Lo7PjBjHso1EZ8y2wP_QXcaBmHpzHVGWZ_6uRm5g/closedform)?

Comment: Wikipedia notes that the [Martha and Bruce Karsh STEM Scholars Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_University#Martha_and_Bruce_Karsh_STEM_Scholars_Program) only awards PhDs or MD-PhDs.

Comment: In that case maybe a [Karshenasi degree](https://wenr.wes.org/2017/02/education-in-iran).

Comment: @Aruralreader Thanks alot, perfect explanation. I have copied the relevant passage into the answers for easier access.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From A rural reader's comment: [WENR World Education News and Review](https://wenr.wes.org/2017/02/education-in-iran)

> **Bachelor (Karshenasi: Karsh.)**
>
> The Karshenasi degree is structurally similar to a U.S. bachelor’s
> degree. Previously known as the Licence, the Karshenasi requires at
> least 130 credits at a university or other institution of higher
> education, and a minimum of four years of full-time study. Students
> must achieve a minimum grade point average of 12 out of 20 to earn the
> degree.
>
> Undergraduate curricula offer a wide range of general education and
> elective subjects along with the degree specialization, which
> typically is concentrated in the last two years of the program.
>
> Karshenasi programs are also offered as short two-year programs on top
> of a Kardani degree. These programs are known as Karshenasi
> Napayvasteh (non-continuous degree) and offer holders of Kardani
> degrees the option to continue their education and complete a
> Karshenasi degree in two years.
>
> **Master’s Degrees (Karshenasi Arshad: Karsh. A.)**
>
> Following the Karshenasi, the Iranian system has a postgraduate
> Karshenasi Arshad degree (previously known as Fogh Licence or Fogh
> Lisans). The award of the credential typically requires 28 to 45
> credits, depending on the program, with an overall GPA of 14/20 or
> better, and the completion of a thesis.
>
> Programs are generally two years in length. These postgraduate degrees
> are referred to as “non-continuous master degrees” (Karshenasi-Arshad
> Napayvasteh) as opposed to “continuous master degrees”
> (Karshenasi-Arshad Payvesteh) found in the professions. (Additional
> detail below.)
>
> NOTE: In recent years, there has been an increase of Western-style
> Master of Business Administration and Doctor of Business
> Administration programs offered by both public and private
> universities in Iran.
>
> Of note for credential evaluators is the fact that private sector
> programs may at times be of questionable quality and often exempt
> students from academic course work on the basis of practical work
> experience.

Comment: Is this specific to Iran? Or more general?

Comment: That is actually a good question. The link above suggests that it is specific to Iran, but my guess is as good as yours. If you have any further information regarding that topic please post it here somewhere.